# Vulkan Validation Layers Not Available

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm new to Vulkan, and I've been following [vulkan-tutorial.com](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/) which has been a great resource so far.

However, one weird thing I've come to realize is that validation layers are supported on my device, but cannot be used without being overridden in *vkconfig*.

Following the tutorial, this is my C++ code at the moment:

```cpp
auto check_validation_layer_support() -> bool
{
    // Get the number of layers
    uint32_t layerCount = 0U;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);

    // Get the layer properties
    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

    // Iterate through to check support
    for (const char* layerName : VulkanInstance::validationLayers)
    {
        bool layerFound = false;
        for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers)
        {
            if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0)
            {
                layerFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!layerFound)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

```cpp
static constexpr std::array<const char* const, 1UL> validationLayers {
    "VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation",
};
```

```bash
source "/opt/vulkansdk/1.3.224.1/setup-env.sh"
export VK_LAYER_PATH="$VULKAN_SDK/lib/vulkan/layers"
export VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS="VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump:VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation"
```

When running *vkconfig* and overriding to use Validation Layers, suddenly everything works perfectly fine. However, if it is not a forced override, it will not work at all.

I'm using the LunarG SDK (1.3.224.1) for Arch Linux (Wayland).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setting for `VK_LAYER_PATH` does not look right.  The setup script should set a "layer path" environment variable for you and so you could try not exporting `VK_LAYER_PATH` after running the setup script.  And if you were to set `VK_LAYER_PATH`, it should be something like `$VULKAN_SDK/etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d`.

Note that the setup script actually sets `VK_ADD_LAYER_PATH` which tells the loader to look in the SDK in addition to and before the system default paths.  Setting `VK_LAYER_PATH` after running the setup script causes the loader to ignore `VK_ADD_LAYER_PATH` and use only `VK_LAYER_PATH`, which was faulty in your case. This left the loader with no good paths to find layers.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! I removed the VK_LAYER_PATH export in my ~/.bashrc file and that seems to have fixed the issue when running the program, though `$VK_LAYER_PATH` is effectively null in Bash's perspective.

Comment: The startup script sets `VK_ADD_LAYER_PATH`, not `VK_LAYER_PATH`.  `VK_ADD_LAYER_PATH` is the same thing as `VK_LAYER_PATH` except that `VK_ADD_LAYER_PATH` also searches the system's layer install directories after looking in the specified path, which is in the SDK in this case.  This lets you load layers that might be installed on your system that are not in the SDK.  So you would not expect `VK_LAYER_PATH` to be set to anything.